# Controls property and FindControl function C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I'm coding a calendar that displays some events. Each day has a button for morning, afternoon and night events, when there are events to show the button is enabled and its color is changed. I am displaying these buttons in an html table and when someone changes the month being displayed the program has to "cleanup" the buttons by disabling all of them and setting their colors to white again. Thing is I was able to enable them by using the FindControl method on the table containing the buttons this way:

```
string butControl = /* id of the button */
Button block = mainTable.FindControl(butControl) as Button;
block.BackColor = Color.Gray;
block.Enabled = true;
```

And it works fine. In my cleanup method I don't want to call all the names of the buttons because there are 105, instead I used this method:

```
    private void CleanUp()
    {
        foreach (Control c in mainTable.Controls)
        {
            Button bot = c as Button;
            if (bot != null)
            {
                bot.BackColor = Color.White;
                bot.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this does not change the color or enabled property of any of the buttons. My question is: Are not the controls in the Controls property of the table the same that can be found via the FindControl method? Or am I doing something wrong when retrieving the controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're using an ASP table, as that would certainly not work. You could get around it in other ways, but if it doesn't matter to you to use some HTML, I would suggest that you restructure it to look like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="mainTable" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

Note the use of only html controls inside the asp:Panel except for the actual buttons. Using ASP, you would have to recursively look for children.

**EDIT:**
Speaking of recursively looking for children, Stefan made that exact suggestion and provided code before I finished writing, and I would definitely recommend his method; he's evidently much less lazy than me.

==================================

Stefan's approach has a slight error in that you can't explicitly typecast without knowing a type, and you can't know a type if you use generics, as he has. Here is a lazy adaptation for use purely with buttons, as you are using it for.

**Do not give this "answer" status. It is a corruption of someone else's work.**

```
public IEnumerable<Button> EnumerateRecursive(Control root)
{
    // Hook everything in Page.Controls
    Stack<Control> st = new Stack<Control>();
    st.Push(root);

    while (st.Count > 0)
    {
        var control = st.Pop();
        if (control is Button)
        {
            yield return (Button)control;
        }

        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            st.Push(child);
        }
    }
}

public void Cleanup()
{
    foreach (Button bot in EnumerateRecursive(this.mainTable))
    {
        bot.BackColor = Color.White;
        bot.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: haha thanks anyway :) ... Well actually mainTable is html <table id="mainTable" runat="server">, would that be horribly wrong? Sorry, kind of new to web programming

Comment: As it's html, it doesn't need a `runat="server"`. That's only needed for ASP controls like an asp:Table.

However, the issue there is that that ID probably won't even register with ASP. Try doing what I did, and make an asp:Panel wrap an html table, then reference the panel's ID in your C#.

Comment: Also, I don't have enough rep to add a comment to Stefan's response, but if you don't want to reuse his function for other purposes, you could just hardcode types. I will edit my response to show you.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried to hardcode the button type too but failed in the attempt, too newbie I guess :S ... again, thanks!!! :)

Comment: I've fixed my answer. Just needed the additional constraint, there's really **no need for hardcoding**! Think it would be better for other people that read these posts if you mark my answer as the correct one...

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the problem that in you're iterating a list of controls rather than the hierarchy? FindControl uses the hierarchy. You can loop the controls as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<T> EnumerateRecursive<T>(Control root) where T : Control
{
    Stack<Control> st = new Stack<Control>();
    st.Push(root);

    while (st.Count > 0)
    {
        var control = st.Pop();
        if (control is T)
        {
            yield return (T)control;
        }

        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            st.Push(child);
        }
    }
}

public void Cleanup() 
{
    foreach (Button bot in EnumerateRecursive<Button>(this.mainTable))
    {
        bot.BackColor = Color.White;
        bot.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

You can implement it using recursion as well, but I usually prefer a stack because it is much faster.

Comment: Visual Studio barks, in the return line it says "Cannot convert type System.Web.UI.Control to T"... Excuse me if the solution to this is obvious, I had never wrote methods with a type as a parameter

Comment: Thank you Stefan, Millie helped us out here, your answer was the base to solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: I should really edit these answers in Visual studio instead of notepad :-) FIXED.

Comment: I didn't even use notepad lol. Just did it in the browser. Between the 3 machines in front of me, 2 of which had VS running, I picked one that did, and proceeded to not use it. And I wasn't aware of the ability to add constraints to generics, so thanks heaps for teaching me something!

Comment: No problem; P.S.: The framework that will be available from my website in a month or so includes a more generic recursive enumerator. It's a quite common operation. Once the URL in my profile is filled in, it is available ;-)